Collapsed column headers in LWC [Winter'25]
While doing a regression test in a Winter'25 sandbox, I found this issue. This is what the header should look like:

And this is what it looks like in the sandbox:

The HTML code for this element:
<lightning-datatable
  key-field="Id"
  data={searchResults}
  draft-values={draftValues}
  columns={searchResultColumns}
  oncellchange={handleChangedQuantity}
  onrowaction={handleSearchResultRowAction}
  hide-checkbox-column="true"
  column-widths-mode="auto"
  min-column-width="10px"
  suppress-bottom-bar="true">
</lightning-datatable>

Both searchResults and searchResultColumns are initialized to []. After the element has contained some data and is re-initialized to [], the headers don't collapse anymore.
I see this for more lightning-datatable elements.
Update 1: (same behavior for Chrome and Edge by the way) by default the browser has full-screen width and height. After clicking the maximize/restore button, the first column has the proper width, all other columns are still collapsed. After clicking the maximize/restore button once more, all columns have the proper width!
Update 2: I thought I'd try the solution listed here: quickly making the datatables invisible and visible. Unfortunately, it doesn't do anything.
Update 3: a solution would be to only show the datatables if they contain data. This works, obviously, but it would change the experience for the users. Maybe not for the worse, but it would be a change.
